# How to correlate filters in ANTS Memory Profiler to find memory leaks?

Tags: testing, memory-leaks, memory-profiling, red-gate-ants

There are different set of filters in ANTS which leads to identification of Memory Leaks.

How do we correlate these filters to get the best result for memory leak identification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through "Walk-through" for ANTS Memory Profiler for better understanding of correlation of results:

Walk-Through: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/walkthrough

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this would be hugely varied depending on the sort of problem you're experiencing. You're best working through the documentation, which has descriptions of what the three classes of filters do, and what they might be used for.

Basic filters: http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/AMP74/Working+with+basic+filters

Object type filters: http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/AMP74/Filtering+by+object+type

Reference type filters: http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/AMP74/Filtering+by+reference

Comment: Thanks! i've gone through the documentation and every filter is clearly explained.